# How does the layout() function work on collections of nodes?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

This is a question that was asked before, and the answer at the time was that an eles.layout() method would be added to allow a layout to be called specifically on a set of elements on the graph. The Github issue was linked and appears to now be closed: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/295

Unfortunately, this call doesn't seem to work, and I see nowhere in the documentation that describes how you can apply a layout only to a predefined collection of nodes rather than the entire graph. Was this implemented and can it be done without directly modifying the layout classes themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 295 is noted as a duplicate, so you should refer to the live ticket:

[Per-element layouts / selective layouts #355](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/355)

Related tickets:

- [Infinite layout APIs #561](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/561)
- [Accessible layout objects #581](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/581)

These features are being considered for 2.3, but per-element layouts (e.g. `eles.layout()`) as of yet has no compelling usecase that isn't already covered by existing functionality.

The utility of an `eles.layout()` function is uncertain.  For one, if only one layout is being used at a time, then it's equivalent to locking nodes you don't want in the layout -- which is simple, and has been supported by the library since the beginning.  Second, I have not seen a usecase or heard one mentioned that requires multiple layouts to be run simultaneously.

If you have usecases related to this, please note so in the appropriate ticket.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I figured out the method of locking the nodes you don't want to layout by looking at the Lumify source. My issue with this is that layouts still try and function as if they were able to move the locked nodes, i.e. a circle will have empty slots because it tries to position immovable nodes in it. I like the idea of locally executable layouts, perhaps centering their layout logic around the centerpoint of the nodes of interest? For example, I grab a node and its neighborhood and I want to lay them out, but layouts have no concept of a local centerpoint.

Comment: Or, as another example, I add a node and its related nodes to my graph, and I want to lay them out in a particular away around where they are dropped on the canvas. I suppose that the lock method partially covers these cases, but it seems like there could be more robust ways of handling local graph layouts. If it is being looked into, great. I wasn't aware of the new issues that you linked, I was only able to find the old one that was closed.